# Auto-populate field value in NewForm.aspx based on another list using REST

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I have two SharePoint 2016 lists: List-A and List-B.

**List-A** has three columns:

- Employee (person/group)
- Supervisor (person/group)
- Contact (Font Awesome envelope icon)

**List-B** has two columns:

- Employee (person/group)
- Supervisor (person/group)

The envelope icon in List-A is linked to List-B's *NewForm.aspx*. When a user clicks the envelope icon in List-A, I would like to auto-populate List-B with the values from List-A ("Employee" and "Supervisor" from the particular row where the icon was clicked). "Employee" will always be the currently logged in user (`_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName`)

Here's my pseudo-code:

- When icon on List-A is clicked (List-B's *NewForm.aspx* opens)
- Query List-A for "Employee" (currently logged in user) and "Supervisor"
- Copy values from List-A to corresponding fields in List-B

What's the best way to accomplish this using the REST API?

Comment: which sharepoint version you're using? why you tagged spo?

Comment: I'm using SharePoint 2016 On-Premise. I removed the SharePoint Online tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could append corresponding item id to the envelope icon attribute,like:

```
/sites/lists/ListB/newform?ID=1
```

Then in the List B newform,we could get List A values with the ID in the url.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List A')/items(id)
```